# gfortran compilation error (installing Quantum ESPRESSO)

Tags: command-line, install

I'm trying to install [Quantum ESPRESSO](http://www.quantum-espresso.org/), but I keep getting an error when I'm configuring the make files (this installation procedure is addressed on page 8 of the [manual](http://www.quantum-espresso.org/wp-content/uploads/Doc/user_guide.pdf)).

In particular, I invoke `sudo ./configure` in my terminal, and I get the following error:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
checking ARCH... mac686
checking setting AR... ... ar
checking setting ARFLAGS... ... ruv
checking for ifort... no
checking for gfortran... gfortran
checking for Fortran compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: in '/Users/malxmusician212/Downloads/qe-6.1':
configure: error: Fortran compiler cannot create executables
See 'config.log' for more details.
```

My config.log is posted [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/Q70x8vwm).

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use `sudo` here?

Comment: @patrix i suppose there isn't; however, i've run it without sudo (i.e. just "./configure") and the error remains...  is there a reason i'm unaware of as to why i shouldn't use sudo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're giving arguments to the "as" (assembler) command, that it doesn't understand.

This is usually caused by you having installed more than one type of "as", and calling the wrong one.

In this case you're actually calling "as" in the /opt/local/ subtree, which is not the system default "as".

Try removing /opt/local/bin/ from your path, and doing a reconfigure - or manually using configure arguments force the compilation to use a different "as" command.

Comment: thank you!  i ran this command: `export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games` and then it worked

Comment: should i delete the other assemblers?

Comment: Depends on whether you need them for other things.

Comment: fair enough, i think i may have screwed up a number of paths/compiler paths because i've tried to get qe to install so many different ways...